# set error code for mongoose validations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using mongoose validation to validate my models. for example:

```
var some_schema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type : [String, 'title must be string'],
    required: [true, 'title is required']
  }
})
```

this schema has custom error messages, I want to set custom error codes too